# Error: illegal assignment list to list

Tags: apex, rest-api, list, wrapper-class, global-methods

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Contact')
    global  class WSgetcontact {
    @HttpGet
    global static list<contact> doGet() {
        WSgetcontact.contactproductwrapper result = new  WSgetcontact.contactproductwrapper();
          list<string> country = new list<string>();
        list<string> product= new list<string>();
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        system.debug('@@@req'+req);
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        
        String contact_UUId = req.params.get('uuid');
        list<contact> conlist = [SELECT  Name, country__c, product__c FROM contact WHERE contact_UUId__c = :contact_UUId];
             for(contact con:conlist ){
            country.add(con.country__c);
            product.add(con.product__c);
              }
        list<price_list__c> pricelist = [select Cost_Per_Month__c,ATM_Fee__c,Card_Replacement_Cost__c 
                                        FROM Price_List__c 
                                        where   Country__c=:country and product__c=:product ];   
        system.debug(pricelist);
          system.debug(result);
        result.contact= conlist;
        result.products=pricelist;
           res.responseBody=blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(result));
        return null;
    }
    //wrapper class for return data
    public class contactproductwrapper{
           public list<Product_Price_List> products;
            public list<contact> contact;
                }
        
    
    
}
```

Getting error in this line

```java
result.products=pricelist;
```

Comment: Please also add the WSgetcontact.contactproductwrapper Inner class in your question

Answer (score 1):

change the wrapper class variable *list<Product_Price_List>* to **list<price_list__c>**

```
//wrapper class for return data
public class contactproductwrapper{
    public list<price_list__c> products;
    public list<contact> contact;
}
```